# MongoDB - $filter 2 array contains object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Let's say I have a document like bellow

```json
{
  fieldA : [
    {
      _id : 1,
      value : 1,
    },
    {
      _id : 2
      value : 2,
    },
    {
      _id : 3,
      value : 3,
    },
  ],
  fieldB : [
    {
      _id : 2
    },
    {
      _id : 3
    },
    {
      _id : 4
    },
  ],
  
}
```

I want to filter which `_id` in `fieldB` has in `fieldA` and take `value` in `fieldA`, add to new field name `fieldC`

Expected output

```json
  fieldC : [
    {
      _id : 2,
      value : 2,
    },
    {
      _id : 3,
      value : 3,
    },
  ]
```

I tried using $filter in $addFields but it returned an empty array

```js
{
  $addFields : {
    fieldC : {
      $filter : {
        input : "$fieldB",
        cond : {
          $in : ["$$this._id", "$fieldA._id"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
fieldC = []
```

Comment: Is `fieldC` just an output or do you seek an *update* back into the collection?

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, your expected behaviour is actually a set intersection behaviour. You may simply "swap" your `$filter` to do `a._id` in `b._id`.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "fieldC": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$fieldA",
          "as": "a",
          "cond": {
            "$in": [
              "$$a._id",
              "$fieldB._id"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_hjMJWPviZq) for your reference.

Comment: Minor note: to vend *only* `fieldC` change `$addFields` above to `$project`.